# Is there any way I can view logs of a Podio application?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, podio

I am trying to integrate a Gravity Form to a Podio application using the [Gravity+ plugin](https://podio.com/extensions/39)

However when I submit the form, I get a success message as normal on the website, but nothing happens in Podio. I don't see any messages anywhere.

Is there a log somewhere in Podio I can look at to see if the message was received but rejected for some reason?

Comment: Does the entry registered on your website?

Comment: @MûhámmàdYäsårK Yes it does

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Podio doesn't expose logs of actions that happens only on the API side. You can see an activity stream for each item though, so if the *action* have really been completed successfully you will find it there.

If you get a success message on Gravity but don't see anything on Podio, I suggest you open a ticket with them to verify whether your configuration is done correctly or not.